# HREF en plantilla .ftl

Tags: html, template, email, alfresco

no tengo mucha idea de ftl ni freemarker, pero necesito montar un enlace HREF en una plantilla que uso para enviar correos, encontré esto:

> **<#assign res=' [HOLA](http://www.ggggggggg.com)'?matches(r'href="(.*?)"')>**

pero no me vale, porque muestra el enlace http... literalmente y yo necesito que me muestre el alias, es decir, HOLA y que tenga el hipervínculo del enlace. lo normal si se hiciera con HTML por ejemplo...
Podéis ayudarme?

Comment: <#assign res='<a href="http://www.hhhhhhhhhhhh.com">HOLA</a>'?matches(r'href="(.*?)"')> es lo que tengo perdón.

Comment: No se como se pone aquí una línea decomenado comentado para que no la interprete...

Answer (score 0):

Así te debería valer: `<a href="URL" style="elSstyle" target="_blank">TEXTO ENLACE</a>`

Para que no te lo interprete, tiene que meterlo como código, con comillas simples ` o usando el botón de las llaves {} en el editor.